# Personalizing direct mail content with additional markers in Direct Mail Typo3

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

Additional fields from the recipient table (e.g. defined by an extension) can be configured in the Extension Manager. You have to switch to "Information" view of EXT:direct_mail and set a comma- separated list of DB fields in "Additional DB fields of the recipie..." (addRecipFields) to make more markers available. These can be used according to the pattern above like `###USER_<some field>###`.

After reading above notes,
First I have add "tx_directmailsubscription_localgender" field to EXT:directmail configration "Additional DB fields of the recipient [basic.addRecipFields]",

then

I have used `###USER_txdirectmailsubscriptionlocalgender###` in my newsletter
But it is not working.

So anyone have solution regarding how to add custom markers in directmail newsletter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Few try I got solution,
We should use 'tx_directmailsubscription_localgender' to EXT:direct mail like following screenshot
[image]

Then we need to use `###USER_tx_directmailsubscription_localgender###` in Newsletter page.